# Should I include the dates of my degrees on my resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, discrimination

Based on how I was taught to put together a resume, I've always listed something like the following for my educational background:

> Education:
>
> Master's Degree, 2000, Large University, Field of Study
>
> Bachelor's Degree, 1985, Small College, Major: My major, Minor: My Minor

However, while reading the question ["How can I find accurate start and stop dates for my resume from jobs that I had 20 to 35 years ago?"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27606/how-can-i-find-accurate-start-and-stop-dates-for-my-resume-from-jobs-that-i-had), it occurred to me that by listing the dates I'm showing my age, and am now getting to a point where age discrimination is likely to occur. Thus, I'm wondering if it is okay to leave the dates of my degrees off my resume.  If it is okay, what format should I use for listing my education?

Comment: Month followed by year will do. So what about the age. All is says you are old and wise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Thus, I'm wondering if it is okay to leave the dates of my degrees off
>   my resume. If it is okay, what format should I use for listing my
>   education?

It's completely okay. For anyone who has been in the workforce for a while, there is no value to the attendance dates for your degrees.

Just list it the same way, minus the dates

> Education:
>
> Master's Degree, Large University, Field of Study
>
> Bachelor's Degree, Small College, Major: My major, Minor: My
>   Minor

Comment: Yes, no one cares about the dates in that context.

Comment: People check that you have a continuous record. Gaps are a red flag